# Qual versão do nodejs para instalar cordova ionic 2.0.0-beta.3

Tags: node.js, ionic

Existe muitas versões do nodejs, observei que se eu estiver com a última versão do nodejs, eu não consigo fazer a instalação de uma versão anterior do ionic, eu tentei após instalar o nodejs é entra no terminal como administrador eu forcei a instalação desta forma (estou usando o Windows 10 e outra máquina com 8.1):

comando : npm install -g cordova ionic@2.0.0-beta.3

gera erro na instalação do ionic.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual o erro que está sendo retornado? E qual seu sistema operacional?

Comment: eu ajustei a minha dúvida com mais detalhes, estou usando o Windows 10 e outra máquina com 8.1:

Comment: Você tem o Python instalado no seu PC?

Answer (score -1):

Vá em https://nodejs.org/en/
Instale a opção da esquerda(6.9.1)
Você vai precisar basicamente do NPM pra instalar algumas dependências, e o próprio ionic.

Após instalar o node, faça:

npm install -g cordova ionic

Após instalar o projeto, verifique se o ionic foi instalado com sucesso digitando o seguinte comando no seu prompt de comando:

ionic

Caso queria iniciar um projeto Ionic 2, digite:

ionic start --v2 meuProjeto sidemenu (ou outro template a sua escolha).
Caso queira a versão 1.0 do ionic, não digite o --v2.

Para mais informações, dá uma olhada em: https://ionicframework.com/getting-started/

Comment: eu ajustei a minha dúvida com mais detalhes, estou usando o Windows 10 e outra máquina com 8.1:

Comment: acabei de editar minha resposta, dá uma olhada

Comment: Eai??? Deu certo?

Comment: esté comando "npm install -g cordova ionic" vai instalar a última versão, e depois se eu fizer isso  "ionic start MyIonic2Project tutorial --v2" vai gera o projeto usando TypeScript isso é o que não quero

Comment: Quero um projeto usando JS normal e não TypeScript

Comment: entendi, então no caso basta não adicionar o --v2

Comment: você já tentou usar estes comandos? "ionic start MyIonic2Project tutorial --v2" ou este "ionic start MyIonic2Project " sabe me falar qual a diferença que vai causar?

Comment: ionic start app tutorial --v2 vai iniciar um projeto Ionic 2 com um template de tutorial, explicando com funcionam as coisas no ionic 2.
ionic start app irá inicializar um projeto Ionic 1, com um template default(acho que o default é o tabs), e ai ele vai criar um projeto com um sistema de rotas baseado em tabs.